# Node; Q Promise delay

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Here are some simple questions based on behaviour I noticed in the following example running in node:

```
Q('THING 1').then(console.log.bind(console));
console.log('THING 2');
```

The output for this is:

```
> "THING 2"
> "THING 1"
```

## Questions:

1) Why is `Q` implemented to wait before running the callback on a value that is immediately known? Why isn't `Q` smart enough to allow the first line to synchronously issue its output before the 2nd line runs?

2) What is the time lapse between `"THING 2"` and `"THING 1"` being output? Is it a single process tick?

3) Could there be performance concerns with values that are deeply wrapped in promises? For example, does `Q(Q(Q("THING 1")))` asynchronously wait 3 times as long to complete, even though it can be efficiently synchronously resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually done on purpose. It is to make it consistent whether or not the value is known or not. That way there is only one order of evaluation and you can depend on the fact that no matter if the promise has already settled or not, that order will be the same.

Also, doing it otherwise would make it possible to write a code to test if the promise has settled or not and by design it should not be known and acted upon.

This is pretty much the as doing callback-style code like this:

```
function fun(args, callback) {

    if (!args) {
        process.nextTick(callback, 'error');
    }
    // ...
}
```

so that anyone who calls it with:

```
fun(x, function (err) {
  // A
});
// B
```

can be sure that A will never run before B.

### The spec

See the [Promises/A+ Specification](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec), [The `then` Method](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec#the-then-method) section, point 4:

> `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code.

See also the [the note 1](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec#notes):

> Here "platform code" means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be implemented with either a "macro-task" mechanism such as setTimeout or setImmediate, or with a "micro-task" mechanism such as MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling queue or "trampoline" in which the handlers are called.

So this is actually mandated by the spec.

It was discussed extensively to make sure that this requirement is clear - see:

- https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/pull/70
- https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/pull/104
- https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/100
- https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/139
- https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/229

Comment: But couldn't the `Q()` function specifically be implemented to return a promise that is initially marked as settled? If you're working with promises, it's highly unlikely that you're relying on your code outside of promises to run before the code within them. Couldn't the `Q()` function immediately settling save a process tick? And what about the other questions? :P

Comment: Ahh I see! Do you know why this is a part of the spec? Essentially, why would the spec choose to have mandatory delays in instances where values should be immediately accessible? Also, I suppose this means that `Q(Q(Q(Q(Q(Q(Q(1)))))))` will have its fulfillment delayed by 7 process ticks?

Comment: @GershomMaes See Issue #229 "What is the intention behind clause 2.2.4 of Promise/A+ spec?" - https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/229 And see the discussions in all of the links in my answer.

Comment: Seems like there's confusion in that discussion, but I get the idea. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Actually Q had an `Q.asap` function that did exactly this, but it was deprecated exactly for the given reason. "*If you're working with promises, it's highly unlikely that you're relying on your code outside of promises to run before the code within them*" - that assumes that you a) understood promises well b) don't make mistakes and c) like to debug race conditions when they happen. It's just the better idea to ensure consistency and avoid the error-prone case. The single microtick delay does absolutely not hurt performance.