# Maximum call stack size exceeded in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I used events in nodejs to implement my logic. And "nextParams" is an event that make function "extractVideo" executed again. I know I used recursive event loop. I tried to used setTimeout(function, 0) and setTimeout(function, 1) in my code, but the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" still appear, I wonder does anybody know how to fix this problem, I am appreciated very much!

```
    videoCrawler.prototype.extractVideo=function(queryStr){ 
       self.on("videoIdArray",function(){
            if(videoIdArray.length){
                self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
            }else{
                self.videomonitor.emit("nextParams");
            }
        });

        self.on("getVideoIdArray",function(videoidarray){
            if(!(videoidarray || videoidarray.length)){
                self.videomonitor.emit("nextParams");
            }
              videoIdArray=videoidarray;
              self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
        });

        self.on("save",function(videodetailinfo){
            if(!videodetailinfo){
                if(videoIdArray.length){
                    self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
                }else{
                    self.videomonitor.emit("nextParams");
                }
            }
            self.saveVideoInfo(videodetailinfo);
        });
        self.on("errorCapture",function(errInfo){             
            if(errInfo.message=="queryStr is not exits"){
                setTimeout(self.videomonitor.emit("nextParams"),1);
            }else if(errInfo.message=="videodetailsinfo is not exits"){
                self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
            }else if(errInfo.message=="videoId is empty"){
                self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
            }else if(errInfo.message=="save fails"){
                self.getVideoInfo(videoIdArray.pop());
            }
        });
        self.getVideoId(queryStr);  
    }
```

below are functions

```
    videoCrawler.prototype.getVideoId=function(queryStr){
      if(!queryStr) this.emit("errorCapture",errInfo);
       //dosomething
       this.emit("getVideoIdArray",videoArray); 
    }

      videoCrawler.prototype.getVideoInfo=function(videoId){
      if(!queryStr) this.emit("errorCapture",errInfo);
       //dosomething
      self.emit("save",videodetails);
      }

      videoCrawler.prototype.saveVideoInfo=function(videodetailsinfo){
       if(!queryStr) this.emit("errorCapture",errInfo);
        //dosomething
       self.emit("videoIdArray");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For certain problems that involve [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), you can turn on the tail call optimization in some versions of Node (since 6.5 but not any more since 8.0!).

See this for compatibility:

- http://node.green/#proper-tail-calls--tail-call-optimisation-

For info on proper tail calls, see:

- http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_5.11

For other cases where you don't have tails calls you should use `setImmediate()` or `process.nextTick()` depending on when you want your code to run, instead of using `setTimeout()` because those are better optimized but `setTimeout()` would still avoid the call stack from growing. But here you don't use `setTimeout()` for every call and that is probably the problem.